# if loop inside a void function not working

Tags: loops, validation, input, parameters, user-input

So I'm doing a program for a class, and I set up an if loop inside a function definition to set parameters for entries. I'm supposed to be taking inputs between 0 and 10 only. But it's only catching the numbers that are less than 0. It won't catch the numbers larger than 10.

```
int main()
{
    float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Judge #1: " << endl;
    getJudgeData(score1);
    cout << "Judge #2: " << endl;
    getJudgeData(score2);
    cout << "Judge #3: " << endl;
    getJudgeData(score3);
    cout << "Score #4: " << endl;
    getJudgeData(score4);
    cout << "Score #5:  " << endl;
    getJudgeData(score5);

    calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);

    return 0;
}

void getJudgeData (float &score)
{
    cin >> score;

    if(score < 0 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Error: Please enter a score between 0 and 10." << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` condition works properly for me, but it's not a loop yet. Therefor it only ask for correct input once. Tested with `gcc version 8.3.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the `if` condition in your `getJudgeData` function into a `while` loop:

```cpp
void getJudgeData (float &score)
{
    cin >> score;

    while (score < 0 || score > 10)
    {
        cout << "Error: Please enter a score between 0 and 10." << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }
}
```

Otherwise the condition will be only checked once, means for the first input of every judge. This isn't intended, if I understood your issue correctly.

Please find more information regarding the `while` loop here:

[while](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while)

Comment: @Jessica: Please check if this answer might help you. If yes, please accept it and/or vote on it. Thanks.